# How can I get an member object from the user_id in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

at the moment, I am trying to learn how to code Discord Bots and I have a question,
how can I get a discord.Member object from the user_id?

```py
@bot.command(name="delete_Roles", aliases=["del"])
@commands.has_role("Mod")
async def delete_Roles(ctx, member_id: int):
    member = getMemberObject(id)
    if member:
        await member.remove_roles(*member.roles, reason="Remove all Roles", atomic=True)
    else:
        await ctx.send("User not found")
```

My Question is what do I need to do instead of member = getMemberObject(member_id).

I would appreciate, if you could help me out.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Guild.get_member` function:

```py
member = ctx.guild.get_member(member_id)
```

or

```py
async def delete_Roles(ctx, member: discord.Member):
```

The member arg is going to be already a `discord.Member` object

Reference:

- [Guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member)

Comment: thanks for your answer, you are helping me a lot with this